# How can I loop through arrays skipping previously referred elements?

Tags: ruby, arrays

Is there a way to loop through two arrays and have them refer to a certain element each time? For example:

```
first_array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
second_array = ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']

first_array.each |item| puts item.get(second_array)
```

The results would look something like:

```
a would work with e
b would work with f
c would work with g    
d would work with h
```

I'm trying to make it so that when a variable from `first_array` is passed to work with `second_array`, it moves to the next variable in `second_array`, skipping the previously used variable.

Comment: **I am not familiar with Ruby** but I would extract this data using a loop structure with a counter up to the total length of your first array. Then I would extract the values at the counter from each array.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean :\

Comment: basically what the others outlined in Ruby syntax underneath

Comment: oh ok, i'm going to look into it now, thanks :)

Comment: you're right @CarySwoveland I thought about that.

Comment: i'm not crazy about votes but i still did it. i'm sure the votes come in handy, but i'm still a noob.

Comment: Mrs. Jane, learning any language (computer or otherwise), is all about detail. You must get in the habit of demanding that all code you write is correct, even if it's just part of a question, and you need to test to confirm that it's correct.  Had you executed `first_array = [a,b,c,d]` in IRB, you would have received the message, `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'a' ...`. One other thing needs to be said: you will get better answers if your questions are clear, precise and correct in all respects. Some members will simply not answer poorly-written questions.

Comment: okie doke, you're right, so I'll do better :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is `zip`.

```
first_array.zip(second_array){|e1, e2| ...}
```

Comment: nice , never got that far down the list of functions... :(

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
first_array.each_with_index { |v, i| puts "#{v} can work with #{second_array[i]}" }
# a would work with e
# b would work with f
# c would work with g
# d would work with h
```

Comment: hmm the reflexes of the young.

Comment: I think i see what you mean, I'm going to try  it out, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that, as in your example, the two arrays are the same size, you could use [Array#transpose](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose):

```
a1 = %w{a b c d}
  #=> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']  
a2 = %w{e f g h}
  #=> ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
[a1,a2].transpose { |s1,s2| puts "#{s1} and #{s2}" }
  #-> a and e
  #   b and f
  #   c and g
  #   d and h
```

Whenever you are working with an array `a` of equal size arrays (here `[a1,a2]`) and want to operate on `[a[0][i],a[1][i],..]` for each `i`, you always have the option of using `transpose` or [Array#zip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-zip). In a sense, they are [Yin and Yang](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yin_and_yang).

You could also just use indices:

```
a1.each_index { |i] puts "#{a1[i]} and #{a2[i]}" }
```

Answer (score 0):

given second array is always at least as long as the first

```
first_array.each_with_index |item,index| do
  puts "#{item} would work with #{second_array[index]}"
end
```

Comment: would i make the index have a += 1 in the loop?

Comment: ruby does that for you.

Comment: okie doke, thank you :)
hey do you happen do know anything about pagination with soundcloud api?
I'm trying to use the "linked_partitioning=1" value along with using the "next href" as well.. 
or if you could  spread the word? :\
@TonyHopkinson

Comment: Nope, not me , another question I should think.